# Is there a way to write a conditional mapped type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types, conditional-types

I've been trying to write a generic type which can take an optional argument of which keys to remap based on another similar type.

My problem is that Typescript seem to dislike this. This is the setup:

```
interface Origin {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
interface SimiliarType {
  a: boolean;
  b: boolean;
}

type Mapped<K extends keyof Origin> = Omit<Origin, K> & {
  [Property in K]: SimiliarType[Property];
};
const mapped: Mapped<'b'> = { a: '', b: false };
// OK
const mapped: Mapped<'a' | 'b'> = { a: false, b: false };
// OK
```

The above code works as expected but then adding the condition seem to change the original behaviour:

```
type ConditionalMapped<K extends keyof Origin | undefined = undefined> = K extends keyof Origin
  ? Mapped<K>
  : Origin;

const conditionalMapped1: ConditionalMapped = { a: '', b: '' };
// OK
const conditionalMapped2: ConditionalMapped<'b'> = { a: '', b: false };
// OK
const conditionalMapped3: ConditionalMapped<'a' | 'b'> = { a: false, b: false };
// ERROR: b is not a string
```

From what I can tell this seem to be a limitation in typescript but I could be wrong. I could create different types for each condition but I'd rather not if there is a way to combine them.

Comment: Here's the linked answer's approach to preventing distribution applied to your code: https://tsplay.dev/w8x14w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into the [distributive behavior of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

This behavior means that when instantiating the type `ConditionalMapped<'a' | 'b'>`, the result will be `Mapped<"b"> | Mapped<"a">` instead of `Mapped<"b" | "a">`.

The simple solution is to disable the distribution behavior. Since the behavior only happens over naked type parameters, we can just wrap the type parameter in  a tuple:

```
type ConditionalMapped<K extends keyof Origin | undefined = undefined> = [K] extends [keyof Origin]
  ? Mapped<K>
  : Origin;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.2-rc#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJWAc1Mg3gWAChlk4AuZAZzAxEwG4iSAjC62hogXyNElkQoAysAC2wADbA4UACoBPAA4oCxUhWYB7TRIhwQjNa2Radeg9yJEwSlAFk4i5QBMAPAGlkEAB6QQzymQAawh5TRg0DGwQAD5kAF40cTBXdCxQABpkdziAMjwmZABtAAUoTWUoG2QcdwBdChFxKRkFZVLyyps6wy5DBE0QamRRRxcKBycINwByZhm4xNx1ZBmZrON4CUoUPqIAen20dyIBobARsemAJgmr2bgZ5AAfVfnFvBWtnY2Kb93DIdjlZCDZlMgAMKDZzAMDAQZwCSTFweLy+CD+QIhMIRNLRF7IACu-ggMFA0wSRJJZJA0w+RXqaL8AWK2PCkXSIDqhQA-MhkdMPDFChQ8aBDKdBsMzjC4QikfcAIwUKH+WHwkCIgXOSnLcirdYmChrZB7QhA1AnQhnaXQ9Xy7W3SF2uWahVTWbvXUrNa-ZD-U2Ao6WyXnZAy+1u7UAZhVLo1WvurhmjwJcwW3v1-z9AbNFvcQA)